# F# signature style question

Tags: f#, coding-style, signature

In my FSI files should I expose the internal functions and mark them as private or just not have them present? I have seen it both ways so I am a little curious.

Comment: Can you give an example of what exactly you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just omit them; I can't think of any advantages to declaring private stuff in a .fsi file.

(Where did you see an example of that?)

Comment: some internal code, so it seemed odd. Just making sure I wasn't missing something

Comment: @Lewisc: You can use the compiler to generate fsi files automatically. If you do it emits nearly everything (from my experience). They likely did not prune the resulting file is why you were seeing private members.